# Image in wrong location in qgis2web

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis2web

I'm using the qgis2web plugin to display a Landsat image and some agricultural fields. Both raster and vector data are in EPSG:4326.
In the QGIS canvas, the vector and raster line up (left side of the attached image) but in the qgis2wweb dialog there is a shift in the raster (indicated by red line). I know it's the raster that's shifted because the vector lines up with OSM background. Has anyone seen this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Leaflet export as well as Openlayers? Leaflet export warps rasters as best it can to the right projection, but OL3 doesn't. Rasters are not qgis2web's strongest feature, and need more development:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/33

Edit:

Another thought. Make sure your project is in 4326, check "Match project CRS", and try Leaflet export.

Second edit:

Changed qgis2web's Leaflet raster output projection from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857, and also fixed the file locking bug.

Comment: When I change to Leaflet I get an error saying that the raster file is already being used in another process. (error in http://pastebin.com/wpY0GQ6x). I also certified that everything is in EPSG:4326 and turned on "Match project CRS". The raster also fell in the wrong location, but different from the previous wrong location). I'll place the data and the project in some public space so you can check.

Comment: Just placed the data in my Dropbox:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19035357/teste_qgis2web.7z   There you will find the original shape and GeoTiff file. Another thing I noticed is that if I load the raster PNG used by OL3 in QGis, it is located in the right place.

Comment: Fixed that Leaflet error (file in use) in master on Github. Re: reopening the output in QGIS, is there an accompanying file (like an .aux.xml) or some such? Just wondering where it gets its georeferencing from.

Comment: Yes, there is a png.aux.xml that I believe is created by web2qgis plugin. At least I did not create it. Forgot to mention that in the file I shared in dropbox, I included the output from qgis2web. As for the Leaflet error, when do the changes in master on GotHub appears in QGis plugin repo?

Comment: Normally changes are released as new versions quite quickly. However, we're at release candidate stage. Given that this is a bug, though, probably RC2 will be out in the next couple of days. In the meantime, you can just download the master branch from Github and unzip it to overwrite your existing qgis2web directory. That's all the QGIS plugins repo does.

Comment: Thinking about this further, the raster might be best off in 3857. If you don't match project CRS, that's the output projection. Vectors are converted to 4326 geoJSON regardless, so don't worry about them.

Comment: I've pushed 1.0.0-RC2 to the QGIS plugins repo. This should fix the file in use error. I've also changed Leaflet's default raster export from 4326 to 3857. Let us know if that makes a difference.

Comment: The Leaflet export now works, using raster projected both in epsg:4326 or epsg:3857. Thanks!! Another minor issue came up, but will open another question for it.    OL3 export, on the other hand, is still placing raster layer in the wrong position, regardless if raster is in 4326 or 3857

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add something to this as I thought I was having a projection issue when my points were not being plotted correctly on the Leaflet output.

Turns out that the Lat/Long are being rounded to 2 decimal points. This was moving my points to the wrong side of the road in this instance; which was obviously incorrect to the eye. I went into the .js file for the specific point and added the complete value which corrected the issue on the webmap.

It appears that the .js can handle the complete Lat/Long without limiting the decimal places to two. Is this something that can be changed in the QGIS2WEB plugin?

Just wanted to pass this along as I might not be the only person to run into this issue. Thanks!

Comment: What setting do you have for 'Precision' in the qgis2web dialog?